# Avoid urllib to replace a file but insted give it a _1 ,_2 like name

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I have a csv file with image urls and given file names in two columns. In the file some file names are repetitive but their b respective links are unique. I want to save all the images. So if 
A given filename.jpg image exists I want the next images to be saved as  filename_2,filename_3.

I use a simple urllib.urlretrieve line to get images

Comment: Use `os.path.isfile` to check if a file exists. If it does, change the name of the new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imports:

```
import csv
import os
import re
import urllib
```

First, store your csv data.

```
file_names = []
urls = []

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for file_name, url in reader:
        file_names.append(file_name)
        urls.append(url)

    file.close()
```

Make a new list to store your new file names in.

```
new_file_names = []
```

Iterate through the `file_names` list.

```
for file_name in file_names:
```

Grab the file extension. There are many image extensions: **.jpg**, **.png**, etc.

> This is assuming the file extension is only 4 characters long including the `.` Anytime you see `[-4:]` throughout the document, be careful of that. If it is an issue, use regex to get the file extension instead.

```
    file_ext = file_name[-4:]
```

Next iterate through the `new_file_names` list to see if we grab any matches with `file_name` from the `file_names` list.

```
    for temp_file_name in new_file_names:
        if temp_file_name == file_name:
```

When we get a match, first check if it already has a `'_\b+'` + `file_ext`. What this means is `_` + `any numbers` + `file_ext`.

```
            check = re.search('_\d+' + file_ext, temp_file_name)
```

If the check is `True`, we now want to see what that number is and add one.

```
            if check:
                number = int(check.group(0)[1:-4]) + 1
```

Now we want to pretty much do the opposite regex as before so we only get the file name + `_` but without all the numbers. Then add on the new number and the `file_ext`.

```
                inverse = re.search('.*_(?=\d+' + file_ext + ')', file_name)
                file_name = inverse.group(0) + str(number) + file_ext
```

This `else` is for when the match is the very first occurence adding a `_1` to the end of the `file_name`.

```
            else:
                file_name = file_name[:-4] + '_1' + file_ext
```

Append the `file_name` to the `new_file_names` list.

```
    new_file_names.append(file_name)
```

Set a folder (if you want) to store your images. If the folder doesn't exist, it will create one for you.

```
path = 'img/'

try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except OSError:
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise
```

Finally, to save the images, we use a `for` loop and zip up `new_file_names` and `urls`. Inside the loop we use `urllib.urlretrieve` to download the images.

```
for file_name, url in zip(new_file_names, urls):
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, path + file_name)
```